# Multiline list of buttons that wrap to fill width of container

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a list of links/buttons in SwiftUI that wrap at the edge of the containing view. The same thing as a `display: inline;` in CSS.

[image]

Comment: You might find helpful my answer in [SwiftUI HStack with Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842453/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap)

Comment: @Asperi Great solution!

Comment: Thanks @Asperi I'll tinker with that!