# How to allow click to select a word and click-and-drag to select multiple words in text

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I would like to be able to, given a string, display that string and be able to select a word by clicking on it and also be able to select multiple words by clicking and dragging over an area that they are partially or entirely in.  I have the clicking down (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61462329/3554470)).  I also have a way of creating a selection box.  I don't know how to get the words that are contained in the box though.  I am using SwiftUI on macOS but could use AppKit if it could be integrated into my project.  A click doesn't always create the selection box for some reason too but that's not the focus of this post.

[image]

```
struct WordDetectionTextView: View {
    
    let words : [String]
    
    @State private var selections: [Int : Bool] = [:]
    
    @State private var dragStartPoint: CGPoint?
    @State private var dragCurrentPoint: CGPoint?
    
    @State private var boxX: CGFloat?
    @State private var boxY: CGFloat?
    @State private var boxWidth: CGFloat?
    @State private var boxHeight: CGFloat?
    
    var body : some View {
        
        var width = CGFloat.zero
        var height = CGFloat.zero

        return GeometryReader { g in
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                ForEach(0..<words.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text(words[i])
                        .foregroundStyle((selections[i] ?? false) ? Color.red : Color.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            let selectionState = selections[i] ?? false
                            selections[i] = !selectionState
                        }
                        .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in
                            if (abs(width - d.width) > g.size.width) {
                                width = 0
                                height -= d.height
                            }
                            let result = width
                            if i < self.words.count-1 {
                                width -= d.width
                            } else {
                                width = 0 //last item
                            }
                            return result
                        })
                        .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: {d in
                            let result = height
                            if i >= words.count-1 {
                                height = 0 // last item
                            }
                            return result
                        })
                }
                if let boxX, let boxY, let boxWidth, let boxHeight {
                    Color.white
                        .opacity(0.5)
                        .position(x: boxX, y: boxY)
                        .frame(width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)
                }
            }
        }
            .frame(height: 300)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0)
                    .onChanged { value in
                        dragStartPoint = value.startLocation
                        dragCurrentPoint = value.location
                        updateBox()
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        dragStartPoint = nil
                        dragCurrentPoint = nil
                        updateBox()
                    }
            )
    }
    
    private func updateBox() {
        updateBoxWidth()
        updateBoxHeight()
        updateBoxX()
        updateBoxY()
    }
    
    private func updateBoxX() {
        guard let startX = dragStartPoint?.x, let currentX = dragCurrentPoint?.x, let boxWidth else {
            boxX = nil
            return
        }
        if startX < currentX {
            boxX = startX + (boxWidth / 2.0)
        } else {
            boxX =  startX - (boxWidth / 2.0)
        }
    }
    
    private func updateBoxY() {
        guard let startY = dragStartPoint?.y, let currentY = dragCurrentPoint?.y, let boxHeight else {
            boxY = nil
            return
        }
        if startY < currentY {
            boxY = startY + (boxHeight / 2.0)
        } else {
            boxY = startY - (boxHeight / 2.0)
        }
    }
    private func updateBoxWidth() {
        guard let startX = dragStartPoint?.x, let currentX = dragCurrentPoint?.x else {
            boxWidth = nil
            return
        }
        boxWidth = abs(startX - currentX)
    }
    private func updateBoxHeight() {
        guard let startY = dragStartPoint?.y, let currentY = dragCurrentPoint?.y else {
            boxHeight = nil
            return
        }
        boxHeight = abs(startY - currentY)
    }
}
```