How can I add a specific background to a specific range of text in SwiftUI?
So I have a random text with some bold keys , and on that some information in the text, I want to be able to attach a specific background (lottie), but I never know where the keys will be on the text. So this must be dynamic.
I try separating the text and apply the BG to the specific one but I always get Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'Text'
 @TextBuilder
func textBuilder() -> Text {
    Text(originalText.prefix(upTo: originalText.range(of: boldText)?.lowerBound ?? "".startIndex))
    Text(boldText)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .background(
            LottieView(animationName: "animation",
                       loopMode: .playOnce,
                       contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
                                    .frame(height: 10)
                                    .offset(CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 12.0))
        )
    Text(originalText.suffix(from: originalText.range(of: boldText)!.upperBound))
}

UPDATE
I found out in https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-pain-links-in-text-b31319783c9e a pretty good and working solution. But the text in this case will not be center.

If the background is a simple color, you can create an AttributeString. But if the background is another View, you cannot create a single Text for this. Put multiple Texts in an HStack. If you need multiple lines, I'd imagine it is easier to write a UIViewRepresentable and work with TextKit instead.

The background will be a lottie. But the text can have multiple lines.

Then you will probably need to use TextKit. Wrap a UITextView with a UIViewRepresentable, find out the rects of the ranges of text where you want a background, and put Lottie views on those rects. I'd imagine this would be quite involved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483735/get-frame-of-a-word-in-swiftui-text this helps if it was just one word, but is multiline text and it could be 1 to three words together to add the lottie
