# How to use LazyVGrid or LazyHGrid to get displayed content based on size?

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to use LazyVGrid or LazyHGrid to get a view like this?

[image]

The Text values are rendered in the box, and if there is no more space near the right border, then it starts on the next row.

I have tried using the LazyGrids but it seems that since I am required to give a minimum column width

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [
   GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 60)),
],
```

The text gets truncated.  Is there any way to accomplish the view in the image above using grids?

Comment: Currently LazyH/VGrid support only *regular* structure, ie under any GridItem configuration they try to layout items with equal rows/columns, so your case is not possible to support now.

Comment: You might find interesting [SwiftUI HStack with wrap and dynamic height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103264/12299030)

Comment: @Asperi Thank you.  Your answer here is what I am looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842453/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap/58876712#58876712

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI HStack with Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842453/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap)