# emulating CSS flex-wrap behavior with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i'm writing a SwiftUI app and would like a container view which "pushes" its children into a row and, once the row fills up, starts wrapping subsequent children to the subsequent row—in other words, a container which emulates the behavior of CSS flexbox's `flex-wrap: wrap` attribute.  the children have variable, dynamic widths, but are the same height (although i suspect most non-insane solutions will be robust to variable heights).  the number of children is also dynamic.

toplevel, my question is just: what's the simplest way to do this?  if i need to dip into UIKit or obj-c land, so be it, but i'd prefer solutions which are standalone (i.e., not `pod Yoga`).

(NB: i am new to iOS dev, but have working familiarity with React and with all the ~newfangled CSS  layouts.)

so far my best lead is the `LazyVGrid` View that ships with iOS 14.  in particular, it seems to me like a single adaptive GridItem with no maximum (defaulting to infinity) should do the trick... but it does not, or at least i haven't figured out how yet.  (the best reference slash only detailed reference for `*Grid` i've found is: https://swiftui-lab.com/impossible-grids/)

i initially tried this:

```swift
let columns = [
  GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 42), alignment: .leading)
]
```

alongside

```swift
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
  Text("Hello, world!")
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("lol")
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("bananananananananana")
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    .border(Color.gray)
}
```

[but that didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXuaO.png).  setting an explicitly large maximum (50000) didn't help either.  my understanding here was that the `LazyVGrid` should allow its children to expand their grid cells, but that's clearly not what's happening here.

i wanted to make sure this wasn't `Text` being all shy and meek and declining to express its size preference, so i tried being more explicit with a frame:

```swift
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 100)
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
  Text("sup")
    .border(Color.gray)
}
```

[but this also doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c3a2.png).  i've gotten the wrapping behavior, but not the "flex" behavior, which at least by my reading is what `.adaptive` purports to do on the tin.

so my secondary question is: what am i misunderstanding about the way that an adaptive `LazyVGrid` performs size proposal to its children and negotiates the size of its "adaptive columns"?  is there a way to do what i want with grids, and if not, why not (and what's a better plan)?

Answer (score 1):

my understanding of `.adaptive` was incorrect—its columns are *always* evenly spaced; the `maximum` argument just allows those columns to expand (in lock-step) so that they collectively fill the parent's space.  i'd thought that each column could *individually* expand to the max width from the min width.

a friend corrected me and linked me an `HStack`-based solution: [SwiftUI HStack with Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842453/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap)

(i'm leaving this question up because the best `Lazy*Grid` writeup i found, linked above, can i think be interpreted both ways on this point, hence my error.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: realised I focused on the wrap not the flex part of your question and don't think this is what you're after.

I think you just need to set the alignment property and then you get the same effect as CSS flexbox's `flex-wrap: wrap` [shown at CSS tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/).

This seems to work for me, only change to your code is setting `alignment: .leading` in the LazyVGrid initialiser. [Result with alignment: .leading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEScJ.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let columns = [
      GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 42), alignment: .leading)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
          Text("sup")
            .border(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```