# SwiftUI Wrapping HStack with Images

Tags: swift, swiftui, hstack

I am trying to make a HStack which contains x number of images and will display them in a wrapping HStack manner (i.e if only 4 of the 7 images fit on the line, then spill the 3 remaining over onto the next line).

I am trying to use the library WrappingHStack (https://github.com/dkk/WrappingHStack) but the result isn't as expected, the images are not wrapping around.

Here is my code:

```
    @State var numEarths : Int = 7;
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        
            Text("If everyone were to live like you, we would need \(numEarths) Earths").font(.title)
            WrappingHStack{
                ForEach(0 ..< numEarths){_ in
                Image("logo")
                
                }
             }
         }
    }
```

Here is the result on the simulator (see, no wrapping)...we should see 7 Earth logo images but you can only see 4 (and a tiny bit of number 5).
[screenshot of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqV7e.png)

Please can someone help me fix this issue? I am new to SwiftUI dev so please go lightly on me if this is a silly mistake. Thanks.

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876712/12299030.

Comment: If you target iOS 14+ I suggest you have a look at LazyVGrid and LazyHGrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `WrappingHStack` library, if you want to achieve what you above-mentioned, you need to do two things:

- Give your `Image` a `frame` so that the `WrappingHStack` can know how many elements to put in per line.
- Change your `ForEach` loop to `WrappingHStack`, because `WrappingHStack` can be used as a `ForEach` to loop over items.

```
WrappingHStack(0..<numEarths, id:\.self) { _ in
    Image("logo")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

[image: Working Solution image]

Comment: That’s right. The reason behind the second bullet point is that `ForEach`’s are handled like an object that is not supposed to be wrapped in that library (author here)