# SwiftUI - is possible to make layout like Flexbox?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new in iOS. Now I'm trying to make some view looks like CSS's [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-properties).

```
struct FlexStack: View {

    let maxItemCountAtLine: Int
    let arr: [String]

    @State var idx:Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< (arr.count/maxItemCountAtLine)+1) { _ in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<maxItemCountAtLine) { _ in
                        Text(arr[idx])
                        plusIdx()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func plusIdx() -> some View {
        self.idx += 1
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

I know the `idx` won't updated because this view is still drawing.

How can I make this work properly?

Comment: What is FlexBox?

Comment: @mahan it's from CSS

Comment: You're probably looking for [LazyVGrid](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid-using-lazyvgrid-and-lazyhgrid)

Comment: You can look for a solution or ideas in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842453/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap/75672314