# How to implement `float: left` or `flex-frap` in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I tried many ways to show texts, (textfields) with variable width like this. First will each line, and let grow vertically. How in SwiftUI?

[image]

Comment: Nothing built in you have to create your own with `SwiftUI.Layout` or `HStack`s

Comment: Can you draft the basic how?

Comment: No, people ask this question once a week, search for Hashtag, wrapping Text, wrapping HStack, the simplest I saw was from Asperi a long time ago It is like 20-30 lines of code. There are so many solutions out there already. I would likely recreate with `Layout` if I needed one it shouldn't take much code since all the math is provided. Maybe someone else will be willing.

Comment: Do you have link to Asperi's solution?

Comment: I can't find Asperi's solution right away, but if you search "SwiftUI Flow Layout" on your favorite search engine, you will find multiple solutions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842453/swiftui-hstack-with-wrap