# SwiftUI Inline Text with an Image Positioned on the Right for a Multiline Text?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-text

I've got an image stored in the Assets folder, and my goal is to append it to a multiline text. I don't want to place it in an HStack; instead, I want it to appear at the end of the text, regardless of how many lines the text spans. Please refer to the image below for a visual example.

[image]

I'm aware that using `Text(Image(systemName: "imageName"))` is a suitable solution, especially for SFSymbols.

However, this approach isn't as effective when dealing with Asset images that exceed the font size of the text. The image below is by using the following code with an asset image.

```
Text(Image("info"))
```

[image]

Comment: You could break up the main text into individual words and then use a custom ```Layout``` implementation that supports wrapping. For example, see [SwiftUI HStack with Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58842453/20386264).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution and wrote a brief article about it. I'm open to exploring alternative approaches.

[Inline Text and Image](https://silviuvr.medium.com/swifui-multiline-text-with-an-inline-image-at-the-right-end-d1e65724c2ab)

This is the code that made things work for me:

```
struct InlineView: View {
   private var text = "This is a multi-line text. It has multiple lines. It has multiple lines. It has multiple lines. It has multiple lines. "
   private var image = "info" // Replace with your image name
   private let font: Font = .system(size: 17)

   var body: some View {
       Text(text)
           .font(font)
       + Text("\(getCustomImage())")
   }

   private func getCustomImage(color: Color = .gray, newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 17, height: 17)) -> Text {
       if let image = UIImage(named: image),
          let newImage = convertImageToNewFrame(image: image, newFrameSize: newSize) {
           return Text(
               Image(uiImage: newImage)
                   .renderingMode(.template)
           )
           .baselineOffset(-1.5)
           .foregroundStyle(color)
       }
       return Text(Image(systemName: "heart.fill"))
   }

   func convertImageToNewFrame(image: UIImage, newFrameSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newFrameSize, false, 0.0)
       image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newFrameSize))
       let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       return newImage
   }
}
```