# Best practice to implement a collection of items with different sizes in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to implement a View in SwiftUI, it has a collection of Buttons with different widths, the layout rule is that if the next button's width can be fit into the same row, then put it next to the previous one with a fixed spacing, otherwise put it in a new line.

The bound width is fixed as well.

What's the best practice to implement this?

[image]

Comment: Search “SwiftUI flow layout” for a variety of solutions

Comment: Maybe look at Grid as well

Comment: You can check out this package: https://github.com/ciaranrobrien/SwiftUIMasonry

Comment: This is one of those things that is deceptively difficult to pull of. Typically I use a third-party package to do it. In short you have to do a few things. #1 you need to track the width of each view, #2 track the space between each view, #4 track which line you happen to be on and I think there's one other thing you need to track. Basically you end up telling the view exactly the position for everything contained in it. Adding in scrolling, vertically or horizontally complicates it further.

Comment: See also [SwiftUI HStack with Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58842453/20386264)